# Add one date to date in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am setting up a MySQL (Maria) where I am going to upload demo data for an application. In the demo date there will be many different dates from the last 6 months.

What I need to do is to keep all dates the same number of days from today all the time. So a date that is x number of days earlier or later than today keep that interval constant.

The demo data will be used in a PHP application so it is maybe an option to run PHP code to change the dates every day, or is it best done any other way?

I have been trying to just add +1, but it does not work on dates.

Comment: Do you need a date? You should store it as number (signed) and deduce the date after extraction depending on current date.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, including @JoelCrypto's suggestion. Another way would be to add (or subtract) the correct number of days dynamically when you retrieve the dates from the DB, which would be the difference between the date the demo went live and today's date. (In other words, if the demo went live 5 days ago, you would have to add 5 days to each date you extracted from the DB.) A third way would be to run a nightly script that bumps the dates forward by a day.

Comment: I think it need to be a date because it  will need to change month and year correctly.  Adding or subtracting the dates dynamically was that I tried, but I could not get that to show correct. When it was change of month it did not change correctly

Comment: What did you try? `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL column DAY)` should have worked.

Comment: That I did not try, but it works fine. Thanks  @Barmar